# ¿Como puedo activar una "function", dentro de otra "function" con una variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, function

Quisiera activar una Función dentro de otra Función con una variable... dependiendo de la variable activaría la otra función. ¿Como se puede hacer?

```js
function mifuncionbase(){
numvar = e.target.href.split("/").pop(); //aqui recibo un numero del 1 al 10 de un href
miotrafuncion+numvar();
}//me gustaria que mifuncionbase active mis otras funciones

function miotrafuncion1(){
alert ("funcionando uno");
}

function miotrafuncion2(){
alert ("funcionando dos");
}
```

con una variable recibida:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si quieres llamar una funcion mediante su nombre, puedes usar window[ nombredelafuncion ]()
ejemplo:

window["miotrafuncion"+"1"]();

tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
function mifuncionbase(){
   numvar = e.target.href.split("/").pop(); //aqui recibo un numero del 1 al 10 de un href
   window["miotrafuncion"+numvar]();
}

function miotrafuncion1(){
   alert ("funcionando uno");
}

function miotrafuncion2(){
   alert ("funcionando dos");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo usando [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval), te dejo comentarios en el código y te recomiendo encarecidamente que revises el enlace que te dejo arriba sobre cómo funciona eval.

```js
function miFuncionBase(){
  let numvar = 1; //Puedes cambiar numvar y verás que funciona
  let func = "miOtraFuncion" + numvar + "()";//Construyo una "llamada a la función" en string
  eval(func);//eval evalúa el código y efectivamente ejecutará la llamada a la función
}

function miOtraFuncion1(){
  console.log("miOtraFuncion1");
}

function miOtraFuncion2(){
  console.log("miOtraFuncion2");
}

miFuncionBase();
```

Comment: agregar que también puede pasar argumentos

eval(fname)(arg1, arg2);

Answer (score 0):

Una buena práctica sería declarar una variable con el nombre de la función a llamar y luego llamarla desde `window` que te permite llamar a una función por su nombre.

```
function mifuncionbase(){
   numvar = e.target.href.split("/").pop();
   let nombrefuncion = miotrafuncion + numvar;
   window[nombrefuncion]();
}

function miotrafuncion1(){
   alert ("funcionando uno");
}

function miotrafuncion2(){
   alert ("funcionando dos");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En JavaScript puedes utilizar un switch, el cual te permite hacer determinadas acciones para cada valor que tome una variable.

```javascript
function mifuncionbase() {
  let num = 1
  switch(num) {
    case 1:   // Cuando num sea 1, ejecuta "miotrafuncion1" y "break"
      miotrafuncion1()
      break   // Sale del "switch" y no ejecuta el código siguiente
    case 2:
      miotrafuncion2()
      break
  }
}
```

Si todas tus funciones serán del estilo `miotrafuncionx`, es mejor usar el método de corchete `window["miotrafuncion" + x]` (como se menciona en otras respuestas), pero si no es el caso, te recomiendo usar `switch`.